# NEO4J-OGM. Error: saving @NodeEntity with its respective @RelationshipEntity causes the stack to overflow (StackOverflowError: null) - stuck in a loop

Tags: java, neo4j, lombok, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have two nodes and 1 relationship. (:Device)-[:WITH_READING {timestamp}]->(:Reading)
For this I have created the following 2 Node entities and 1 RelationshipEntity.
When I save the Device NodeEntity using Neo4jSessionFactory.getInstance().getNeo4jSession().save. I get the StackOverFlow error, because it just runs in a loop between the Node and RelationshipEntity.

How can I fix this.

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:173) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:120) ~[na:na]
at com.path.Device.hashCode(Device.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
at com.path.DeviceReading.hashCode(DeviceReading.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
at com.path.Device.hashCode(Device.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
at com.path.DeviceReading.hashCode(DeviceReading.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
at com.path.Device.hashCode(Device.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
at com.path.DeviceReading.hashCode(DeviceReading.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
at com.path.Device.hashCode(Device.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
at com.path.DeviceReading.hashCode(DeviceReading.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:124) ~[na:na]
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity(label = "Device")
public class Device {
    @Index
    @Id
    @Property(name="deviceId")
    private String id;

    public Device(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "WITH_READING")
    Set<DeviceReading> deviceReadings;
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RelationshipEntity(type = "WITH_READING")
public class DeviceReading {
    private Long id;
    
    @Property(name = "timestamp")
    private long timestamp;

    @JsonIgnore
    @StartNode
    private Device device;
    @EndNode
    private Reading reading;
}


@AllArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity(label = "SensorReading")
public class Reading {
    @Id
    @Property(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidGenerator.class)
    @Convert(UUIDConvertor.class)
    private UUID id;

    @Property(name="isExtrapolated")
    private boolean extrapolated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I replaced the @Data lombok annotation with just the @Getter and @Setter for the relationshipEntity = :WITH_READING. And now it works just fine.
Not sure why though.